# R - How to classify each row in a dataframe depending on partial matching with another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, stringr

I have two dataframes (df1 and df2), here is the df1:

```
SAMPLE NAMES
1_a
1_b
1_c
2_a
2_b
3_a
4_a
4_b
```

Here is df2:

```
ID  GROUP   
1   X
2   X
3   Y
4   Z
```

Here is what I want to do - I want to add a new column to df1 which will indicate the group of the sample, based on partial matching with the ID column of df2. Therefore, samples "2_a" and "2_b" from df1 should have the same group as "2" in df2.

Desired output:

```
SAMPLE NAMES    GROUP
1_a             X
1_b             X
1_c             X
2_a             X
2_b             X
3_a             Y
4_a             Z
4_b             Z
```

So far I have tried using a stringr package and writing a for loop:

```
for (i in df1[, 1]){
  for (j in df2$ID){
    x <- which(str_detect(i,j))
    class <- df2[j,1]
    df1$group[i] <- class
  }
}
```

but it keeps giving me the error:

> Error in UseMethod("type") :
> no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

What did I do wrong? Also, is there a way to do this using the apply() function instead of loops?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` option

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
 separate(., col = SAMPLE.NAMES, into = c('SAMPLE', 'NAMES'), sep = "_", convert = TRUE) %>% 
 left_join(df2, by = c('SAMPLE' = 'ID')) %>% 
 unite(., col = SAMPLE.NAMES, SAMPLE, NAMES)
#  SAMPLE.NAMES GROUP
#1          1_a     X
#2          1_b     X
#3          1_c     X
#4          2_a     X
#5          2_b     X
#6          3_a     Y
#7          4_a     Z
#8          4_b     Z
```

We first `separate` the column 'SAMPLE.NAMES' of `df1` in two, such that we can `left_join` `df1` with `df2` by 'SAMPLE' and 'ID'. In the last line we `unite` the columns 'SAMPLE' and 'NAME' back into 'SAMPLE.NAMES'.

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(SAMPLE.NAMES = structure(1:8, .Label = c("1_a", 
"1_b", "1_c", "2_a", "2_b", "3_a", "4_a", "4_b"), class = "factor")), .Names = "SAMPLE.NAMES", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, GROUP = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("X", 
"Y", "Z"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "GROUP"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why your for-loop is not working is that `str_detect()` only takes strings as input, but you are trying to use it on the ID column in `df2`, which is a numeric vector. There are other issues with your for-loop as well: in particular, you define an object `x` which is never actually used afterwards, and so your code will not select the elements you want using `str_detect()`.

Here's another option if you want more of a `stringr` solution. It uses neither for-loops nor `apply()` (at least, not directly).

It works by using regex to extract only the numeric characters from your "SAMPLE.NAMES" column to link each sample to its numeric ID. Afterwards we simply join the dataframes together and select the columns you want:

```
# Example dataframes
df1 <- tibble(SAMPLE.NAMES = c("1_a", "1_b", "1_c", "2_a", "2_b", "3_a", "4_a", "4_b"))
df2 <- tibble(ID = c(1,2,3,4),
              GROUP = c("X", "X", "Y", "Z"))

df1 <- mutate(df1, ID = as.numeric(str_replace_all(SAMPLE.NAMES, "_[abc]", ""))) %>%
       left_join(df2) %>%
       select(-ID)

# Output:
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  SAMPLE.NAMES GROUP
  <chr>        <chr>
1 1_a          X    
2 1_b          X    
3 1_c          X    
4 2_a          X    
5 2_b          X    
6 3_a          Y    
7 4_a          Z    
8 4_b          Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Just merge on the portion of the string before the underscore:

```
> df1$ID <- sub("_.+$","",df1$SAMPLENAMES)
> df1
  SAMPLENAMES ID
1         1_a  1
2         1_b  1
3         1_c  1
4         2_a  2
5         2_b  2
6         3_a  3
7         4_a  4
8         4_b  4
> merge(df1,df2, by="ID")
  ID SAMPLENAMES GROUP
1  1         1_a     X
2  1         1_b     X
3  1         1_c     X
4  2         2_a     X
5  2         2_b     X
6  3         3_a     Y
7  4         4_a     Z
8  4         4_b     Z
```